# DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry() is giving NoSuchEntryException

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay : liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5
I've a requirement to upload the profile pic image into my app. I'm using

```
DLFileEntry object to save the uploaded image into database.
DLFileEntry dlFileEntry =DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, groupId, repositoryId, dlFolder.getFolderId(), file.getName(), mimeType, title, description, changeLog, fileEntryTypeId, null, file, is,
                    file.getTotalSpace(), serviceContext);
```

And using the below code I'm updating the status to approved to see the uploaded image in UI

```
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(userId, dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), file.getName(),
                    MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), title, description, "Draft to save", true,
                    dlFileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), null, file, null, file.getTotalSpace(), serviceContext);
```

But the above code is giving

```
com.liferay.portlet.asset.NoSuchEntryException: No AssetEntry exists with the key {classNameId=20011, classPK=23439}
```

I understood that AssetEntry is not being created for this dlFileEntry object.

But why it is missing?

As per my understanding the AssetEntry object should be created when we call updateFileEntry() (Second code snippet) method. 
But why its not creating the AssetEntry object? Am I missing anything here?

Even I tried the below method

```
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, dlFileEntry.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId(), 
                    WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, new HashMap<String, Serializable>(), serviceContext);
```

This is also throwing the same exception

Answer (score 2):

I've created the AssetEntry manually in my code using the below code.

```
AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(userId, groupId, new Date(), new Date(), DLFileEntry.class.getName(), 
                    dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), dlFileEntry.getUuid(),dlFileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), 
                    null, null, true, new Date(), null, new Date(), mimeType, title, description, "", "", 
                    themeDisplay.getLayout().getUserUuid(), 0, 0, 0, true);
```

Is it a proper way to create the AssetEntry for a DLFileEntry object? Czzz I'm not able to figure out why its not being created when I call the above two Util class methods.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem as you. 
It appears to be a bug in Liferay, cf. [this link](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-58451).

It would seem you now have to use the DLAppService instead of DLFileEntryLocalService.

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Kate Smith

Comment: Could you elaborate way more why?

Comment: @SterlingArcher : This is the advice given in the comments in the attached link. We are currently testing the solution to see if it works for us.

Comment: Hi Kate SMITH: Thanks for the reply. I've seen that issue in liferay, but the above code solved my issue, so I didn't touch it. Please let me know, if using DLAppService solves your problem.